# Quadratic Forms and Derivatives of expressions in Matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra

I have some very basic Matrix calcualtion problem. I've been searching on the web for quite a while, but I cannot find anything.
Say we want to minimize the following in the vectors $a$ and $b$.
$$(Y-X_1a-X_2b)'(Y-X_1a-X_2b)$$
First, I rewrite this as

$$Y'Y-Y'X_1a-Y'X_2b-aX_1'Y+bX_2'Y+aX_1'X_1a+bX_2'X_2b+aX_1'X_2b+bX_2'X_1a$$

My first doubt is: Can I simply write that like:

$$Y'Y-2Y'X_1a-2Y'X_2b+aX_1'X_1a+bX_2'X_2b+2aX_1'X_2b$$

My matrix calculation rules would not really lead me there. But I think I have seen some expression like this before...

Second, I take the derivatives. With respect to $a$, does it look as follows?

$$-2Y'X_1+X_1'X_1a+2X_1'X_2b$$

And with respect to $b$:
$$-2Y'X_2+X_2'X_2b+2aX_1'X_2$$

Thank you for helping me with those fundamental questions. Probably the answers are super-obvious...

Felix

Comment: what is $(Y-X_1a-X_2b)'(Y-X_1a-X_2b)$ for $a,b$ being vectors?

Comment: Ah! if you treat $Y,X_1,X_2$ as scalars this makes sense but then $Y',X_1',...$ not. 
So your $Y'Y-Y'X_1a-Y'X_2b-aX_1'Y+bX_2'Y+aX_1'X_1a+bX_2'X_2b+aX_1'X_2b+bX_2'X_1a$ is wrong.

Comment: I'm going to delete my answer ok?

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is a least squares problem. I assume $Y$ is $n\times 1$, $X_1$ is $n\times p$, $X_2$ is $n\times q$, $a$ is $p\times 1$, 
$b$ is $q\times 1$.  Then your expression is 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - x_{1i}'a - x_{2i}'b)^2
$$
so the values for $a$ and $b$ that gives minimum solves the 
least-squares problem.  (here $x_{1i}$ is the $i$-th row of $X_1$, written as a columnn vector. Equally for $x_{2i}$.

You can read about least-squatres here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-squares ....

Comment: yes, it's indeed OLS. I am wondering more about the technicalities. This should just be an example.